# Registrar data de alteração de duas celulas em uma só

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

O seguinte código detecta se foi feita uma alteração em uma celula da coluna I ou J, e registra a data e hora que a alteração ocorreu na coluna M e N.

Eu quero que houvesse um só registro, ou seja, que ele não registre na coluna N, mas apenas na M. Mas não está dando certo, ele acaba registrando uma alteração para cada celula em duas celulas respectivas, como na figura.

Como alterar isso?

```
function onEdit(event) {
 var ActiveSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var capture = ActiveSheet.getActiveCell();
   if(capture.getColumn() == 9 || capture.getColumn() == 10 && ActiveSheet.getName() == "AlertaCompleto" ){
     var add = capture.offset(0,4);
       var data = new Date();
       data = Utilities.formatDate(data, "GMT-03:00","dd-MM-yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss' '");
       add.setValue(data);
   }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
​